# Not able to display content on webpage using flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Need some help, not getting the content from the database not sure why this is happening

using python flask,sqlalchemy with a small sqlite database

I need to see the content from the database displayed on the web page.
At the moment I see only the Home link which is static in the template file.
app.py contains a part of this

```
    @app.route('/page/<int:page_id>')
    def view_page(page_id):
        page = db.session.query(Pages).filter_by(id=page_id).first()
        return render_template('page.html', id=page.id, title=page.title.decode(),
                               content=page.content.decode())
```

page.html (this is the template)

```
    {% extends "master.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% for page in pages %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('view_page', page_id=page.id) }}"></a><h3>{{ page.title.decode() |truncate(150)}} 
    </h3></a>
    <p>{{ page.content.decode() |safe | truncate(350) }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="http://localhost:5000">Home</a>
    {% endblock %}
    </html>
```

Comment: You have `for page in pages` but you're not passing `pages` in `render_template`?

Comment: Not sure what your comment shows. The function in the question does not have a `pages` keyword argument passed to `render_template` so the for loop in the template is never going to do anything

Comment: Actually I fixed the issue thanks to you.
I got my requirement wrong and was on the wrong track till I saw your reply where you mentioned about the pages keyword which brought me on the right track thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send model with your return template.

```
@app.route('/page/<int:page_id>')
def view_page(page_id):
    pages = Pages.query.all()
    return render_template('page.html', pages=pages)
```